# What are the acceptable values for termwinkey?

Tags: key-bindings, terminal, macvim

What are the acceptable values for termwinkey? From VIM's documentation, it appears that any single keystroke (multi-byte or not) should be valid.

However, setting it to `<D-'>` (my first choice) or to `<C-;>` result in "Invalid argument" errors and other options such as `<C-z>` are accepted but don't actually work from the terminal as a termwinkey. For example, a double press doesn't change focus back from the terminal to the editor.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I just tried this with `<C-z>` and it worked for me, `<C-z> :` opens the Ex command-line, and `<C-z> w` siwtches to another window. I can see how `<D-'>` or `<C-;>` can be problematic, since Vim can't always recognize all kinds of key combinations, usually depending on which terminal is being used and so on... But it's still interesting to understand how Vim is detecting that that particular key combination is invalid, so this is an interesting question indeed!

Comment: It's nothing special. Just `<C-;>` never works in Vim. I believe there must be an existing answer about mapping key notations that do not work. The only difference is that `:nnoremap` fails silently, while `:set` gives error message.

Comment: double-pressing `termwinkey` sends the key to the running job. (below `:help terminal-typing`)